# how to replace/remove these type of dates using regex or is their any best way possible?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df of value

df

```
values

2018-04-22:11:09:35
2018-04-22
2018-apl-22
2018-APR
20-JAN-2018
2018-04-22:11:09
2018-04-22:11
2018/04/22:11:09:35
2018/04/22
2018/apl/22
2018/APR
20/JAN/2018
2018/04/22:11:09
2018/04/22:11
2018 04 22:11:09:35
2018 04 22
2018 apl 22
2018 APR
20 JAN 2018
2018 04 22:11:09
2018 04 22:11
```

These dates formats should be removed in a string. any advice?

I have tried this:

```
df['values'].str.replace('\s+[\W\d]+', '')
```

Most of them are not replacing. The accepted output should be :

```
values
```

I want them to be removed in a string.

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: want them to be removed in string.

Comment: Try `.str.replace(r'\s*(?:\d{1,2}[- /](?:\d{1,2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})(?:[- /]\d{4})?|\d{4}[- /](?:\d{1,2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})(?:[- /]\d{1,2})?)(?::\d{2}(?::\d{2}){0,2})?', '')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMbduq/1))

Comment: it isn't working

Comment: miss to know where the string to removed is? anywhere in string ,at the end....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unstructured and huge. But  it'll work like a charm

```
((?:\d{1,2}[- /](?:\d{1,2} | [a-zA-Z]{3})(?:[- /]\d{4})?|\d{4}[- /](?:\d{1,2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})(?:[- /]\d{1,2})?)(?::\d{2}(?::\d{2}){0,4})|\d{2,4}(?:-|/| )\d{1,2}(?:-|/| )\d{1,2}|\d{2,4}(?:-|/| )\w{2,4}(?:-|/| )\w{1,4}|\d{2,4}(?:-|/| )\w{2,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would remove anything that starts with at least two digits: `replace('^\d{2,}.*', '')`.

I'm not sure if there are other lines in your file which begin with digits and that you may want to keep as this pattern would remove them as well.